# How to update ViewModel ni PartialView then post the updated ViewModel from View?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I don’t know if my title makes any sense however let me explain what I am trying to do.

I have a product view with a **ProductViewModel** and a `Html.BeginFrom(“AddToCart”, “Cart”)` for adding a product to the cart.

ProductView:

```
@model Webshop.ViewModels.ProductViewModel

@{ Html.RenderPartial("_TextEditor", Model); }

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EditorImageUrl)
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="@Model.Product.MinimumOrder" min="1" max="9999" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
}
```

In the product view I also render a partial view that takes the same **ProductViewModel**. In the partial view I have a ckeditor bound to my ProductViewModel.EditorHtml property like so `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EditorHtml)`. I need to submit the EditorHtml to generate an image on another server. I do this by using Ajax.BeginForm. In the GenerateImage Action where I request my image to be generated I set the ProductViewModel.EditorImageUrl with the returned ImageUrl.

PartialView TextEditor:

```
@model Webshop.ViewModels.ProductViewModel
<div id="designForm">
    <button type="button" id="modal-opener" class="editorInput"><img src="@Model.EditorImageUrl" alt="Texteditor"></button>

    <div id="dialog-text-editor">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GenerateImage", "Image", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "designForm", HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "closeDialogCallback" }))
        {
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model .ProductId)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model  => model.EditorHtml)
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" title="Prewview" id="btnGeneratePreview">Preview</button>
                <button type="button" title="Close" id="btnCancel">Close</button>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Texteditor Dialog
        $('#dialog-text-editor').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            modal: true,
            title: "TextEditor",
            width: 550,
            height: 550,
        });

        $('#EditorHtml').ckeditor();

        $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog-text-editor").dialog("open");
        });

        $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
           $("#dialog-text-editor").dialog("close");
        });
    });

    function closeDialogCallback() {
        $("#dialog-text-editor").dialog("close");
    }
</script>
```

ImageController

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public PartialViewResult GenerateImage(ProductViewModel viewModel)
{
    //In this method I set viewModel.EditorImageUrl
    CreateImage(viewModel);


    return PartialView("_TextEditor", viewModel);
}
```

This is where I need some guidance. How can I submit my ProductViewModel to my CartController with all the properties populated with values from my Ajax post in the PartialView? These values are always null.

Comment: You shouldn't. Just pass back the product ID and the quantity to the `AddToCart` method. There is no point degrading you sites performance by rendering additional html and then posting it back. Better to just get the product from the database in you post method if you need it.

Comment: Sure I can get the product from the database in the post method but I still need the EditorImageUrl generated by the Ajax.BeginForm in my partial view.

Comment: I assumed you would be saving `EditorImageUrl` so you could retrieve it later, but I guess you could always include a hidden input in the main form and update its value with the value of `EditorImageUrl` in the `OnSuccess` function

Comment: I didn't get your point, you are having two different forms that will do different posts to the server side, one for the Cart and one for the Product. The Cart post cannot see the Product values because they are outside of the Cart form, so submit Cart "Add to Cart" does not know anything about the other Product form.

Comment: Yes, the first form posts to a controller action that generates an image for the product. You can look at it as configuring the product before adding it to the cart. I need to set some properties in my viewModel before submiting AddToCart and I need those values in the CartController. I know the code above is not complete. I need some guidence on how to approach this kind of problem.